# Android: crash on drawPicture() call?

Tags: android

I have an application which displays a series of custom views in a LinearLayout.  The LinearLayout is in a ScrollView.  The custom views draw a picture, when their onDraw method is called.  Generally this works fine.  But occasionally the application crashes on a drawPicture() call.  When it crashes, no exception seems to be thrown, but I do get this message in logcat: "Wrote stack trace to 'data/anr/traces.txt'".

The contents of traces.txt is below:

```
DALVIK THREADS:
"main" prio=5 tid=3 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x2aac2250 self=0x84d00
  | sysTid=412 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=unknown handle=2130112448
  at android.graphics.Canvas.native_drawPicture(Native Method)
  at android.graphics.Canvas.drawPicture(Canvas.java:1404)
  at com.MyView.onDraw(PDFPageView.java:100)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6534)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6537)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6537)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6537)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6537)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6537)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1849)
  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1349)
  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1114)
  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4325)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=17 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x2e4262b0 self=0x351ab8
  | sysTid=420 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=unknown handle=3480528
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x195468> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1535)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:317)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:131)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1996)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:359)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1001)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1061)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

"Binder Thread #3" prio=5 tid=15 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x2e3e9cc0 self=0x191798
  | sysTid=419 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=unknown handle=1738736
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=13 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x2e3e9c00 self=0x1a7510
  | sysTid=418 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=unknown handle=1792360
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=11 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x2e3e9b40 self=0x1aae60
  | sysTid=417 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=unknown handle=1738512
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"JDWP" daemon prio=5 tid=9 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x2e3e82a0 self=0x1b82a0
  | sysTid=416 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=unknown handle=1792208
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=7 RUNNABLE
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x2e3e81e8 self=0x1b9420
  | sysTid=415 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=unknown handle=1791968
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"HeapWorker" daemon prio=5 tid=5 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x2d68c4c8 self=0x1b9968
  | sysTid=413 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=unknown handle=1792792
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

This is the logcat output:

```
W/WindowManager(   53): Key dispatching timed out sending to com.mypackage/com.mypackage.MyActivity  
W/WindowManager(   53): Dispatch state: {{KeyEvent{action=1 code=82 repeat=0 met
a=0 scancode=229 mFlags=8} to Window{4387d7f8 Keyguard paused=false} @ 129122478
0532 lw=Window{4387d7f8 Keyguard paused=false} lb=android.view.ViewRoot$W@4387d4
08 fin=false gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=Window{4392eb90 com.mypackage
s/com.mypackage.MyActivity paused=false}}}  
W/WindowManager(   53): Current state:  {{null to Window{4392eb90 com.mypackage
s/com.mypackage.MyActivity paused=false} @ 1291225159009 lw=Window{4
392eb90 com.mypackage/com.mypackage.MyActivity paused=false} lb=an
droid.os.BinderProxy@4392e9b8 fin=false gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false
 mcf=Window{4392eb90 
com.mypackage/com.mypackage.MyActivity paused
=false}}}  
I/ActivityManager(   53): ANR in process: com.mypackage
(last in com.mypackage)  
I/ActivityManager(   53): Annotation: keyDispatchingTimedOut  
I/ActivityManager(   53): CPU usage:  
I/ActivityManager(   53): Load: 0.71 / 0.81 / 0.44  
I/ActivityManager(   53): CPU usage from 19028ms to 19ms ago:  
I/ActivityManager(   53):   com.mypackage: 34% = 34% user + 0% kernel / f
aults: 24 minor  
I/ActivityManager(   53):   system_server: 2% = 1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8
minor  
I/ActivityManager(   53):   com.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel  
I/ActivityManager(   53):   adbd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 72 minor  
I/ActivityManager(   53): TOTAL: 38% = 36% user + 2% kernel  
I/ActivityManager(   53): Removing old ANR trace file from /data/anr/traces.txt  
I/Process (   53): Sending signal. PID: 514 SIG: 3  
I/dalvikvm(  514): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3  
I/dalvikvm(  514): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'  
I/Process (   53): Sending signal. PID: 53 SIG: 3   
I/dalvikvm(   53): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3   
I/dalvikvm(   53): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'  
I/Process (   53): Sending signal. PID: 96 SIG: 3  
I/dalvikvm(   96): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3  
I/dalvikvm(   96): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'  
I/Process (   53): Sending signal. PID: 223 SIG: 3  
I/dalvikvm(  223): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3  
I/dalvikvm(  223): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'  
I/Process (   53): Sending signal. PID: 140 SIG: 3  
I/dalvikvm(  140): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3  
I/dalvikvm(  140): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'  
I/Process (   53): Sending signal. PID: 120 SIG: 3  
I/dalvikvm(  120): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3  
I/dalvikvm(  120): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'  
I/Process (   53): Sending signal. PID: 172 SIG: 3   
I/dalvikvm(  172): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3  
I/dalvikvm(  172): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'  
I/Process (   53): Sending signal. PID: 175 SIG: 3  
I/dalvikvm(  175): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3  
I/dalvikvm(  175): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'  
I/Process (   53): Sending signal. PID: 94 SIG: 3  
I/dalvikvm(   94): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3  
I/dalvikvm(   94): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'  
W/WindowManager(   53): No window to dispatch pointer action 1  
W/WindowManager(   53): No window to dispatch pointer action 1  
W/WindowManager(   53): No window to dispatch pointer action 0  
W/WindowManager(   53): No window to dispatch pointer action 1  
D/dalvikvm(   53): GC freed 12498 objects / 629776 bytes in 174ms
```

Comment: Sometimes, traces.txt says nothing. You better paste the logcat output.

Comment: Thanks, my logcat seems pretty uninformative, but I added it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a crash, it's an ANR (Application Not Responding.) It means your application is taking too long to respond to an event (more than 5 seconds.)

Comment: thank you.  could you provide any insight on why I am getting this ANR on my drawPicture() call?  It's confusing because it occurs randomly, often the same Picture draws fine... then randomly produces this ANR.

Comment: Sounds like it's not drawPicture() that's causing the issue, but something else in your application.

Comment: are you calling Thread.sleep() in any where? why don't you try drawBitmap ?? I am making a game with this and I am drawing too many pictures even animation but I don't have any problem yet.

Comment: I hope till now you have found some good solution, if yes then I request you to please share your knowledge. Thanks very much